# Python - @classmethod to behave like @property

Tags: python, python-3.x

i'm doing a class with chainable methods, the problem is that there are some methods with `*args` parameters, those parameters can receive objects of the same class.

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self, x=''):
        self.x = ''

    @property
    def tab(self):
        self.x = '\t'
        return self

    def concat(self, *args):
        self.x += ''.join(str(a) for a in args)
        return self

    def surround(self, *args):
        args = tuple(['('] + list(args) + [')'])
        return self.concat(*args)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.x
```

No problem with that, you can do:

```
obj = A()
obj2 = obj.tab.surround('x', 'y')
print str(obj2)

output: \t(xy)
```

But if i want to pass the `tab` method to the `surround` method, it should be:

```
obj = A()
obj2 = obj.tab.surround(A().tab, 'x', 'y')
```

Is there a way to call the `tab` method without instanciating an object? I mean, something like this:

```
obj = A()
obj2 = obj.tab.surround(A.tab, 'x', 'y')  # Note the lack of parenthesis.
```

I was looking for answers making something like `@classmethod` + `@property`, but none of them solve my problem. A solution for python 2.x and 3.x would be appreciated because i want to make it compatible for both version, but a solution for only 1 version is appreciated too.

Comment: `tab` just returns `self`, so you can simply do `obj.tab.surround(obj, 'x','y')` Or even `obj.tab.surround(obj.tab, 'x','y')` if `.tab` had another type of side-effect... generally that gets messy to begin with and I would avoid such a design altoghether...

Comment: More importantly, *what should `tab` return for a classmethod*? It is dealing with instance state. Note, you could write your own descriptor to have this behavior, btw.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga but if my object has a long string `x`, passing the same object will duplicate the string.

Comment: I am doing several methods whiches return different strings, (using my code example) if i want a string like this `\t(\t\ŧabc)`, i would like to type it like this `A().tab.surround(A.tab, A.tab, 'a', 'b', 'c')`, not `A().tab.surround(A().tab, A().tab, 'a', 'b', 'c'), because it looks ugly if i want to build a long complex chainable call with many object instances.

Comment: Why don't you just put an attribute `A.TAB` that has the regular tab. You are trying to create too clever of an interface, IMO. In any case, you can write your own custom descriptor that allows you to return something else. If I have a second later I can show you an example

Comment: Yes, i just woke up thinkg about making it a class variable, so it would be something like `A().tab.surround(A.TAB, A.TAB, 'x', 'y')` =). Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `class attribute`
It's a property for the class not an instance of the class.
`class attribute` can be implemented by 2 ways as below:

```
class A:
    way_1 = 'tab_1'
    
    @classmethod
    def way_2(cls):
        return 'tab_2'
```

```
print(A.way_1)
print(A.way_2())
```